# JavaFx & CSS: white line in the popup component of a ComboBox

Tags: css, javafx, properties, combobox

I have a problem with the CSS properties of a ComboBox-Popup. In the picture you see a tiny white line between rounded border an the list cell element. 
I think this line is a background color or a border from a other css property.
Have you any idea which css property I must change?

This picture show you on the right side my problem with the white line. On the left side you see a menubar without any line.

[image: white line in combo-box-popup]

In this screenshot I have removed all combobox css properties and you can see a gap beetween the border an the selected cell.

[image: white line without any combo-box-popup properties]

Here is the css combobox property of my stylesheet.

```
-fx-base and fx-color = dark grey background color
-fx-accent = green hover and highlight color.
```

```css
 .combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-color: -fx-base;
    -fx-background-color:
        derive(-fx-color,-40%),
        derive(-fx-color,100%),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color, 15%) 0%, derive(-fx-color, 40%) 15%, derive(-fx-color,55%) 75%, derive(-fx-color,15%) 100%);
  
   -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
   -fx-background-radius: 0 6 6 6, 0 5 5 5, 0 4 4 4;
   -fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.083333em; 
   
}.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-accent;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-accent;
}
```

Comment: Check your application with [`ScenicView`](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) and consult http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html to find the relevant CSS element to be changed.

Comment: @hotzst That's actually tricky in this case: iirc if you try to expand the tree view in scenic view to see the scene graph for the combo box, because you take focus away from the combo box it closes, and so the popup is removed from the scene graph (and hence from scenic view...).

Comment: @James_D that's right. 
That's why i use now the Scenic View sources with a simple "don't remove the popup implementation".
I still have not found the solution.

Comment: This exact problem has been posted before on here, and was answered. I can't find it now. IIRC it was some subtle configuration of the content pane underlying the list view (remember the cells in a list view are placed in a scroll pane...). So I think that white line is the background of something like the virtual flow for the list view used in the combo popup, or something along those lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The transparency for the list-view was not set.

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```